# How do you create a Vortex Smoke Ring?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I want to create a Smoke Ring as the outer ring for a portal.

Example 1:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_ring#/media/File:Vortex_ring.gif

Example 2:

[image]

It doesnt HAVE to be a vortex ring.

A revolving smoke ring would be enough for a start

Example 3:

[image]

I tried to to a torus smoke ring, affected by vortex force fields, in different ways. But that got me nowhere.

Does it even make sense to do it with actual smoke ?

Or is there a better way to do it with particles ?

Comment: Those the screenshots posted by you are reference images? You want to achieve something like that or this is what you came up to so far?

Comment: Those are references.

Comment: Three examples are kinda different. I'll try to answer for the first picture.

Comment: That would be awesome. I'll take any help on this i can get